# Como puedo resolver este problema con vue, vuetify, vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify, vue-router

Les comento: Estoy haciendo un tp para la carrera. Tengo que usar vue desde js, vuetify, y vue-router. Lo que me pasa es que nose porque solo me toma el vuetify, pero no los 2 componentes de vue que creé ni las rutas. Creo que es un problema por el orden de los scripts en el index.html o algo asi. Tampoco tengo mucha experiencia en vue, asi que puede ser que algo este mal en mi codigo tambien.

Aviso, es un proyecto muy básico para armar tareas, y también hay cosas que solo están de prueba, como los parallax de vuetify.

Dejo el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <title>Parcial 2 - Aplicaciones para dispositivos móviles</title>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>    
    <v-app> 
    <div class="container contenedor-tareas"> 
        <header class="row">
            <nav class="col navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fondo-header">    
              <img src="imagenes/logo-sitio.png" alt="Logo del sitio" class="p-1" style="width: 150px;">               
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-fijo" aria-controls="menu-fijo" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menú Hamburguesa">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start justify-content-md-end" id="menu-fijo">                          
                  <ul class="w-75 navbar-nav justify-content-around">                       
                      <li class="nav-item"><router-link class="nav-link" to="/" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Home</router-link></li>                                           
                      <li class="nav-item"><router-link class="nav-link" to="/contacto" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Contacto</router-link></li>                                                                  
                  </ul>                                            
              </div>                                             
            </nav>    
        </header>  
      <router-view></router-view>
                    
    
            <template id="tareas-1">
               <v-parallax dark src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg">
                  <v-row align="center" justify="center">
                    <v-col class="text-center" cols="12">
                       <h1 class="row">Organizador de Tareas</h1>       
                       <div class="row">  
                          <p class="col-7 animate__backInUp">La matriz de Eisenhower es una técnica para priorizar tareas que bien podría ser la respuesta a tus problemas de listas de pendientes sobrecargadas y a esas notificaciones de pesadilla.<br>Es una manera fácil y , sin embargo, extremadamente efectiva, de averiguar cómo priorizar tus tareas de tal manera que las más importantes no se opaque con respecto de las tareas urgentes, repentinas e inesperadas.<br>La idea general es que todas tus tareas se pueden organizar en cuatro cuadrantes, cuyos ejes corresponden a la importancia y la urgencia. Estos cuatro cuadrantes tienen valores que van desde 1 hasta 4 según su prioridad.</p>
                          <img class="col-5" src="imagenes/matriz-de-eisenhower.png" alt="Matriz de Eisenhower">
                          <form-tareas class="col-12"></form-tareas>                                            
                       </div>                       
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
               </v-parallax>
            </template>

            <template>
                <v-parallax height="300" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material2.jpg"></v-parallax>
             </template>
             <contacto></contacto>
           
    </div>
    </v-app>  
    
   
   
    <script src="js/vue.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>   
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>  

    <script src="js/router/rutas.js"></script> 


    <script src="js/componentes/form-tareas.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/componentes/contacto.js"></script>         
    
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Y el archivo de rutas.js en en que se encuentras las rutas del vue-ruter y el inicializador de vue:

```
const home = { template: `<template id="tareas-1"></template>`, 
                   name: "home"
}
const contacto = {template: `<contacto></contacto>`, 
                      name: "contacto"
}


const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: home },
    { path: '/contacto', component: contacto },
    { path: '*', redirect: '/' }  
]
  
      
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
});




const app = new Vue({   
    el:".contenedor-tareas",
    router,  
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

En los scripts los que dicen "form-tareas.js" y "contacto.js" de la carpeta js, son dos componentes distintos de vue que hice, que si se ve son llamados en el html ambos.

Para mi es tema o del orden de los scripts en el html, o por donde ubique el inicializador de vue.

Si me ayudan a resolver esto dentro de las 18hs restantes se los agradecería mil. Hasta les pagaría algo, tendria que ver cuanto por el tema del cambio :D, pero unos $1500 argentinos.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente contesto muy tarder, pero si necesitas usar vuetify, lo más recomendable es que crees tu proyecto desde el cli de vue, y luego, lo agregues como plugin.